# Следует ли коммитить в git промежуточные копии когда библиотека вообще не готова

Tags: git

Я так понимаю система **git** служит для контроля версий библиотеки и т.п.

Но если стоит иная задача: промежуточные копии когда библиотека вообще не готова. Например, добавил класс, в нём несколько функций. Библиотека не готова, она не рабочая, но мне нужно сделать точку восстановления. (Скажем, я не уверен точно каким путём идти дальше, чтобы можно было вернуться к этому состоянию, или же просто резервная копия случай сбоя). Коммит делать, как мне кажется нецелесообразно, существуют ли другие пути для этой задачи?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мой вариант работы - репозиторий лежит в интернете, работаю с нескольких мест. Коммиты до пуша хранятся локально, поэтому они больше для истории. Пуш в репозиторий в тестовую ветку в любом состоянии - чтобы при продолжении с другого места было доступно текущее состояние. В любом случае благодаря истории коммитов всегда можно вернуться на любой этап.

Но при этом вся разработка ведется в отдельной ветке, перед заливкой на боевой сервер рабочей версии - слияние с мастером, перед итоговым пушем в репозиторий дополнительный тест.

Правильная идеология - завести ветку testing, в которую коммит без ограничений, пуш по настроению, но слияние с мастером только работоспособной версии.

На возможной развилке можно создать новую ветку, потом победивший вариант вливается в testing, тестируется и уходит в мастер.

И как написал предыдущий докладчик - использовать тэги для отдельных вех.

Comment: "Коммиты до пуша хранятся локально..." - а что, бывает как-то иначе? Они всегда создаются локально.

Comment: я всего-лишь сказал очевидную вещь

Answer (score 11):

Как раз еще для этого git и существует. Коммит - это сохранение локальных изменений, это не публикация. Вы в любой момент можете просмотреть историю коммитов и откатиться на нужный. По большому счету, коммит - это и есть "точка восстановления".

А можете сделать ветку, и в этой ветке работать над какой-то фичей. Переключаясь между ветками, получаете два варианта - код стабильный и код с фичей. После отладки можете слить и удалить ветку. Если не смогли заставить фичу работать, просто удаляете ветку и возвращаетесь к основной.

Answer (score 7):

> Коммит делать, как мне кажется нецелесообразно

Гит создан именно для того, чтобы делать коммиты и делать их часто. Можете воспринимать коммиты как сохранения в опасной стрелялке — вы можете сохраняться в каждой удобной ситуации, перед каждым углом и дверью. И не делайте из разработки рогалик, в котором ошибка приведет к тому, что нужно начинать всё заново. Только постарайтесь давать сохранениям осмысленные имена, иначе они будут бесполезны. Ограничивает вас только место на диске (которое расходуется довольно эффективно, там есть сжатие и переиспользование).

> Скажем, я не уверен точно каким путём идти дальше, чтобы можно было вернуться к этому состоянию, или же просто резервная копия случай сбоя)

Резервная копия - каждый коммит является резервной копией.

```
git add <имена файлов и папок>
git commit -m'какое-то сообщение, отражающее суть коммита'
```

Посмотреть историю коммитов и выбрать какой-нибудь:

```
git log
```

Вернуться к нужному коммиту/состоянию:

```
git checkout <sha1 коммита>
git checkout <имя ветки>
```

Каким путем идти дальше — создаем ветку, она представляет собой альтернативный путь.

```
git branch new-branch-name
```

> для контроля версий библиотеки

Когда ваша библиотека достигнет статуса релиза, можете сделать очередной коммит и отметить его тегом (tag)

```
git tag Release-1.0
```